# How can I write 7 byte Integer value to DataOutputStream, which contains 15 digits?

Tags: java, integer, byte, dataoutputstream

I have to write 7 byte Integer value to DataOutputStream, this Integer contains 15 digits. How can I do that?

Comment: In what radix? Binary? Decimal? Octal? Hex? Base64? Packed decimal? Zoned decimal?

Comment: And how do you get a 7-byte integer value in Java?

Comment: @EJP In Decimal.
Basicly I have to send a value that containt 15 digits, and it has to by 7 byte value

Comment: @Gonzo It must be *packed* decimal: two digits per byte. You are going to have to sort out your requirement first. Then, if it is packed-decimal, you are going to have to tell us *which* packed-decimal format you are using: unsigned, sign leading, sign trailing. Then tell us how this value is presently represented in your Java code.

Comment: Convert to long and truncate the high byte.  If it needs to be displayable characters then something like Base64 would be required, after converting to long first.

Comment: @EJP -- Packed decimal requires 1/2 byte per digit.  15 digits would require 7.5 bytes.  Packed decimal can't be used directly if it must fit into 7 bytes.

Comment: Actually, Base64 won't work.  15 decimal digits is 13 hex digits and would require 19 characters in Base64.  So I don't think there's any scheme that would work with printable characters.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks then the requirement isn't implementable. Decimal radix, 15 digits, 7 bytes. Packed decimal comes closest to that, but there is clearly something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 bytes = 56 bits
that means you can represent numbers up to 2^56 which is more than necessary for 15 digit long numbers.

just convert the number to binary and store it in those 7 bytes that you're sending.

Comment: @Gonzo As you have marked this answer is correct, decimal radix cannot have been a requirement at all, contrary to your confusing responses above.

Answer (score 0):

7 bytes = 56 bits, you can use long to store 15digits integer

And convert it into bytes :

```
long val = ...
byte [] b = new byte[7];  
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){  
    b[7 - i] = (byte)(val >>> (i * 8));  
}
```

/ writing from hand, may mess sth with indexes or shifts /